# Buy ecommerce on web mobile

Tags: iphone, android, paypal, google-checkout

I have an iphone app and android app which are ecommerce "shops"

In these apps, I want to create a "web" view to enable the user to buy my products (i.e. clothes, ...) via Paypal web-mobile or Google Checkout web-mobile

Am I going against the terms and conditions ?

If yes : are there other solutions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at In-App billing. http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html

This will enable users to purchase with their existing Google Checkout/Market accounts.

Comment: I believe that in-app billing is restricted to virtual goods - they don't want you buying real-world stuff with that particular billing system.

Comment: That is rigth, in-app is for buying, say, a magic wand for your game character.

Answer (score 0):

For web apps, have a look at Google In-App Payments (currently in developer-preview mode):

https://sites.google.com/site/inapppaymentsapi/

Answer (score 0):

> Mobile Express Checkout is PayPal’s
>   Express Checkout service tailored to
>   mobile devices. Mobile Express
>   Checkout screens are optimized for
>   webkit browsers for iPhone and
>   Android.  It is easy to transition
>   your desktop checkout experience to
>   mobile devices.  To help with this
>   transition PayPal has some best
>   practices you should review.  These
>   suggestions can improve the user
>   experience and result it higher
>   conversion rates.

There is lot about mobile express checkout

https://www.x.com/blogs/Sidney/2011/04/15/mobile-express-checkout-quick-start

As well as lot about this payment gatway and sample code

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECOnMobileDevices

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_code